# Next.js: how to use different env file for different environment?

Tags: environment-variables, next.js, development-environment, production-environment

Below is the code from package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
},
```

Below is my next.config.js file, here console.log always **undefined**

```
require("dotenv").config();
console.log(process.env.BASE_URL)
module.exports = {
  env: {
    API_BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

And this is in the .env.development

```
BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:3000'
```

When I ran the **npm run dev** command,
it prints on terminal "**Loaded env from /var/www/html/next/next-SC/.env.development**"

So, why the console prints undefined always.

I'm using next js version "10.0.4"

Comment: Because file nextjs config would be loaded before env file loaded.

Comment: Shouldn't the env var in your `.env.development` be set like `BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: In my Ubuntu server, I just set different environment variable in my local and server. They are fetched automatically. Just need to remember that, if you want to expose the environment variable to public, you have to prefix, NEXT_PUBLIC

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using React with nextjs.  If not, then please disregard this answer.  I am doing the same thing.  React has built in support for env vars.  All you need to do is to prefix REACT_APP to your environment vars.  So, in your .env.development or .env.staging, etc., you can have REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://blah.com.  You can then access them in your app using process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL.  Then to build based on environment, I have (I am using craco, you would just use your normal build command)

```
"build:nightly": "env-cmd -f .env.nightly craco build",
"build:nightly": "env-cmd -f .env.staging craco build",
"build:nightly": "env-cmd -f .env.beta craco build",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For development environment, name the file `.env.development`, for production `.env.production`.

Next.js has built-in loader for environment variables. So `dotenv` or similar packages aren't needed. Just add the files. It will be loaded automatically (see [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)).

Answer (score 0):

in next.config.js

```html
const { resolve,join } = require('path');
const {config} = require('dotenv');
let path=resolve('../')
config({ path: join(path,'.env') })
let MAIN_URL=process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_MAIN
console.log("MAIN_URL",MAIN_URL)
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    API_BASE_URL: MAIN_URL
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).